# Calculating Quantiles based on a column value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-science

I am trying to figure out a way in which I can calculate quantiles in pandas or python based on a column value? Also can I calculate multiple different quantiles in one output?

For example I want to calculate the 0.25, 0.50 and 0.9 quantiles for

**Column Minutes in df where it is <= 5 and where it is > 5 and <=10**

```
df[df['Minutes'] <=5]

df[(df['Minutes'] >5) & (df['Minutes']<=10)]
```

**where column Minutes is just a column containing value of numerical minutes**

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DataFrame.quantile` accepts values in array,

Try

```
df['minute'].quantile([0.25, 0.50 , 0.9])
```

Or filter the data first,

```
df.loc[df['minute'] <= 5, 'minute'].quantile([0.25, 0.50 , 0.9])
```